# setting and removing JFrame.setContent

Tags: java, swing

When an application is executed, e.g., a JFrame is instantiated and populated with some content; if the end user then makes some selection that repopulates the JFrame's content panel should the programmer make sure that the original content is removed before adding the newly selected content, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Could you use the code you are using for this currently? Generally if you add components to the frame, then need to change them, you can remove the components, add the new ones, then call revalidate(), or use a card layout and change the component being shown

Comment: Thanks, dbrown93, for your time. This information helps me along my journey.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest and the best solution: use the tool built specifically for this job -- a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). This will allow you to easily swap JPanel or other "views" with ease. If the view always changes to another specific view, this can be as easy as calling `next()` on the CardLayout. If you want the ability to swap to a number of possible views, then call its `show(...)` method.

If you absolutely must do the swapping "by hand", then yes, I think that you would want to remove the covered components from the container. You would also need to manually call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container after the swap so that the layouts are all called and so that any dirty pixels are cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks, Hovercraft, your timely feedback was very helpful.